# Можно ли мониторить изменения memcached?

Tags: node.js, redis, nosql, memcached

пишу чат на socket.io, бек клиента php, сокет сервер на node.js, общение между ними происходит по средствам memcached. Дошел до написания прав для пользователей, баны и прочее. Каждый раз при получении от клиента сообщения проверять наличие каких либо данных в mysql/memcached конечно вариант, но хотелось бы спросить вот о чем. Существует ли механизм или инструмент позволяющий отлавливать апдейт ключа/базы или еще чего нибудь, что бы на стороне сокет сервера я обновил например список забаненых и не возвращался к этому до нового апдейта.

Не совсем важно что это redis, mongodb или memcached. Главное что бы работало с php и node.js

Comment: Если вы боитесь за производительность, то один только сокет сервер на пшп убьет вам больше, чем постоянный опрос хранилища данных. Хранить данные в слое кэширования - тоже заявка на выстрел в ногу.

Comment: @etki "сокет сервер на node.js". А как еще можно общаться безопасно между серверами, кроме субд,сессий?

Comment: Да, по диагонали прочитал, но все равно вы по-человечески только одно ядро процессора на ноде сможете утилизировать. Ничего страшного не будет, если вы будете читать данные в момент необходимости, противоположный подход гарантирует вам проблемы в случае рассинхронизации (если какое-то сообщение потерялось или сообщения в процессе доставки поменяли порядок). Если очень сильно хочется, можно подрубить брокер сообщений и из приложения же его и вызывать, но см. выше какие могут быть проблемы.

Comment: @etki ясно. Наверное на этом и остановлюсь. Но все же вообще бывают способы посмотреть реализацию тригеров, событий называют как угодно, но смысл по идее один, которые будут работать на беке. Нашел один вариант, дописать в mysql функцию на Си, и использовать её в триггерах